# DiscordAPIError: Unknown role

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a command in discord.js in which the bot finds the highest role it can give to a person and gives it to the person.

```js
      const myrole = message.guild.me.roles.highest.rawPosition
      const therole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.rawPosition = myrole-1)
      const person = message.guild.member(client.users.cache.get("the id"))
      person.roles.add(therole.id);
```

And I get the following error:

```js
    (node:18926) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role
        at RequestHandler.execute (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d8568466-4a2a-4c3a-ac47-cee06cded9bb/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.2.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is not checking if `r.rawPosition` is equal to `myrole - 1` it is defining `r.rawPosition` as `myrole - 1`

```js
const myrole = message.guild.me.roles.highest.rawPosition
const therole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.rawPosition === myrole-1)
const person = message.guild.member(client.users.cache.get("the id"))
person.roles.add(therole.id);
```