# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a few lines of code that are causing issues,

```
role = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name = "Muted");
member.roles.add(role.id);
```

This produces the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Marvel-Infinity-Dev-Build/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/Marvel-Infinity-Dev-Build/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
at async GuildMemberRoleManager.add (/home/runner/Marvel-Infinity-Dev-Build/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js:96:7)
```

I have no idea what the issue is and im really confused, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Try add role, not only role id

Comment: @王仁宏 I tried that, it gave the same result

Comment: Are you sure u can find a role named mute in cache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DiscordAPIError: Unknown role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091857/discordapierror-unknown-role)

Comment: Oh. He write role.name = ‘mute’, it must be role.name===‘mute’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude you need to use `===` instead `=` in line 1!